# Is there a way to show content of a word file only if macros are enabled?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want the client to see the document only if he enabled macro.

I've found the following code which should work on excel by hiding an showing sheets, couldn't find a "word version" of the code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets("Request").Visible = xlVeryHidden
        .Sheets("Patching").Visible = xlVeryHidden
        .Sheets("SACM Attributes").Visible = xlVeryHidden
        .Save
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets("Request").Visible = True
        .Sheets("Patching").Visible = True
        .Sheets("SACM Attributes").Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

I would like to "force" the client to enable macro if he wants to see the document, either by hiding the text and showing it only if he pressed "enable macro" or by creating a password prompt that will require him to do that(The client will receive the password by mail or by other similar ways.

Thanks in advance,
Avi.

Update:
Using @Gareth suggestion I've come up with this(placing a picture in front of the text and pressing enable content to show it):

```
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="^g", _ ReplaceWith:="", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

My problem is that if the picture is not in the default layout(like square/ in front of text) the ^g isn't recognising it...
P.S I know the picture can be manually deleted.

Comment: Sadly i don't think that's an option in Word (though i`m no expert), but you could build the content (or the parts that makes the document valuable) via VBA at runtime... so if the client doesn't enable macro, he doesn't get what he wants. Reverse the process on closing the document, but also probably add a before save event (if there is), to prevent saving the document already populated with the content you are trying to hide.

Comment: You cannot do this in the way that you could with Excel, and bearing in mind that VBA passwords are really easy to hack, there are a couple of things you can do.  One is to make it really hard for the text to be read.  You could place full-page images on each page telling the user to enable macros and delete them when the opening macro runs.  Or you could make the text hard to read by scrambling it.  **But** if someone sent me a Word document with VBA I would **never** open it unless I was 100% sure about where it came from and what the code did.

Comment: @FAB Thank you, I've managed to write using the event "Document_Open" and "selection.typetext text:=<my text>", this is not the most desired outcome but it works and it's really close.

Comment: @Gareth Thanks you, this is a good idea.
I know the risk of opening a file from unknown source, especially one that runs code.

Answer (score 0):

**Perhaps:**

```
Private Sub Document_Close()

ThisDocument.Range.Font.Hidden = True

End Sub

Private Sub Document_Open()

ThisDocument.Range.Font.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Save it in `ThisDocument`

It will hide everything before closing the Document. And Show everything once the document opens and Enable Macros is clicked.

**#Note** - This is not Equivalent to the Excel's `xlveryhidden`, the can be undone if user knows how to Show the Data without running the Macro.

Comment: This only replicates what you can do manually as well, and is easily undone by the user... (if they have a clue though...).

Comment: @FAB .. Yes .. added a Note for that :)